# Как убрать прокрутку элемента QComboBox?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qcombobox, qscrollbar

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.comboBox = QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet(''' 
 QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}''')


        self.comboBox.addItem("1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("2")
        self.comboBox.addItem("3")
        self.comboBox.addItem("1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("2")
        self.comboBox.addItem("3")
        self.comboBox.addItem("1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("2")
        self.comboBox.addItem("3")
        self.comboBox.addItem("1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("2")
        self.comboBox.addItem("3")
        self.comboBox.addItem("1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("2")
        self.comboBox.addItem("3")
        self.comboBox.addItem("1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("2")
        self.comboBox.addItem("3")
        self.comboBox.addItem("1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("2")
        self.comboBox.addItem("3")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Ui_MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Но когда я навожу курсор мышки на место, которое указано красной стрелкой, то список начинает сам прокручиваться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если из стиля `QComboBox`

```
 QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

убрать эти две строчки, то эта прокрутка пропадает.
Но мне нужно сохранить эти два стиля

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**autoScroll**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwBY9.png) : bool
>
> Это свойство определяет, включена ли автопрокрутка.
>
> Если для этого свойства установлено значение **True (по умолчанию)**,
> `QAbstractItemView` автоматически прокручивает содержимое представления.
>
> Автопрокрутка отключается установкой этого свойства в **False**.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.comboBox = QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet(''' 
 QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(222, 0, 0);
}
''')
        
        self.comboBox.addItem("1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("2")
        self.comboBox.addItem("3")
        self.comboBox.addItem("11")
        self.comboBox.addItem("12")
        self.comboBox.addItem("13")
        self.comboBox.addItem("21")
        self.comboBox.addItem("22")
        self.comboBox.addItem("23")
        self.comboBox.addItem("31")
        self.comboBox.addItem("32")
        self.comboBox.addItem("33")
        self.comboBox.addItem("41")
        self.comboBox.addItem("42")
        self.comboBox.addItem("43")
        self.comboBox.addItem("51")
        self.comboBox.addItem("52")
        self.comboBox.addItem("53")
        self.comboBox.addItem("61")
        self.comboBox.addItem("62")
        self.comboBox.addItem("63")

        self.comboBox.view().setAutoScroll(False)                # !!! +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(200, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]